# Turn off WPF default UI animations (checkbox etc.)

Tags: wpf

I am intending to use the default Aero theme but am unhappy with the fade-in that happens when checking a checkbox as well as some of the other 'flashy' effects like the button pulses.

Is there a way to turn off these effects / animations without re-templating the controls?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. These are the default effects used when the system theme is Aero (i.e Windows 7 and Vista).

You would have to perform some sort of re-styling or re-templating to remove the elements that include these animations (i.e. the controls in Presentation.Aero).

You could explicitly load a different theme, such a Luna, Royale, or Classic. But, then you'd lose the Aero look. This [blog](http://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/) explains how to explicit load the Aero theme, but you can replace that with one of the others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, it's kind of sad that WPF is so limited; Microsoft went one step in the right direction but couldn't quite get the separation of style down.