# CheckBox Binding Slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I'm in a bit of a bind here (no pun intended); I have a large collection of view models (500+)  which are displayed using an `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.  Each of these view models exposes a `Boolean?` whose value is bound to the `IsChecked` property of a `CheckBox` on the user interface.

The problem is this... whenever I attempt to update all the checkboxes at once it is horrendously slow.  Almost 10 seconds to update a list of 500 items.  If I run the updating code in a seperate thread I can almost watch the checkboxes be updated one by one.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this process is so slow and how I could improve it?

I have considered that perhaps the non-virtualizing nature of the `WrapPanel` could be the guilty party.  However, when I bind to the `IsEnabled` property instead of `IsChecked` I see an interesting result; namely that changing the value of `IsEnabled` to true is slow as expected, but changing to false happens instantaneously.  This makes me suspicious that the checkbox animation is at fault because as far as I can tell visually there is no animation when disabling a checkbox, but there is when enabling.  Profiling has revealed that the vast majority of time is spent in the `PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged()` method.

Example code below, I'm unfortunately forced to use .NET 3.5:

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SampleViewModel}">
            <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeInPrinting, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Boolean? _includeInPrinting;
    public Boolean? IncludeInPrinting
    {
        get
        {
            return _includeInPrinting;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_includeInPrinting != value)
            {
                _includeInPrinting = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IncludeInPrinting);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Slow Code:

```
foreach (SampleViewModel model in ChildItems)
{
    model.IncludeInPrinting = false;
}
```

EDIT: For what it's worth I'm also seeing a spike in memory usage whenever I check all or uncheck all the checkboxes. ~10MB

EDIT: The performance analysis below seems to confirm that animation is definitely the issue.
[image: Performance Analysis Hot Path]

Comment: What you can try is to disable the Property notification on all the items, change all the properties, and then raise a NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset on the collection holding all the items.

Comment: http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/

Comment: @dowhilefor Forgive my ignorance, but how do I raise `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` on an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @Micah Hahn, I tried your code in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. It took me 2-3 seconds to check/uncheck 10000 checkboxes.

Comment: @KaiWang Are you running an OS with Aero animations on?

Comment: @BasBrekelmans I've tried the VirtualWrapPanel, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: @Micah Hahn, yes, win 7 with Aero on. If you suspect it's animation that causes this, why not restyle the checkbox to remove those animation?

Comment: @Micah Hahn, 10+ seconds for 500 checkboxes is too slow even without visualization.

Comment: @KaiWang Yes I agree its far too slow... I have considered restyling, but it appears you have to redo the entire template which I'm not particularly interested in.

Comment: @Micah Hahn, Restyling is just for proving your theory. Actually I doubt the problems lies on the default style. Restyling a control is pretty easy. What do you mean by "redo the entire template"? entire template of what?

Comment: @KaiWang Can you give an example then? I had looked online before for examples on how to do so and didn't find anything that made it look easy. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490421/turn-off-wpf-default-ui-animations-checkbox-etc) [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/224ebb33-81db-44d3-bcbe-98873786df03/where-is-wpf-hiding-checkbox-checkmark-fade-inout-animation)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the following control which is open source on CodePlex..

http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/ (Note: I have no affilication with Virtualizing Wrap Panel)

Due to the large number of view models you are working with this would drastically improve performance for you.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, I have not been able to get this custom control to work.  I get the same exception mentioned here [WPF - Virtualising WrapPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736989/wpf-virtualising-wrappanel), but the accepted answer did not fix it.